# JQuery get index of form input array

Tags: jquery, html

```
<input type="number" value="88" name="fee[]" style="width:60px">
<input type="number" value="60" name="fee[]" style="width:60px">
<input type="number" value="20" name="fee[]" style="width:60px">
<input type="number" value="90" name="fee[]" style="width:60px">
```

i want to get index of name array in jquery which look like below

0
1
2
3   4

my script

```
$('input[name="fee[]"]').each(function() {          
    alert($(this).index()); //result undefine
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
$('input[name="fee[]"]').each(function(index) {          
    alert(index);
});
```

If not, please explain further.

Note the **index** parameter in the function, this variable will hold the iteration value.

Answer (score 1):

Your expected result is wrong, you got 4 elements so `0 1 2 3`.

So if I understood your question correctly, this is what you want

```
 $("input[name='fee[]']").each(function(i, v) {
        alert(i);
 });
```

The first arg to the each function is the index and the second is the element in the current iteration.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: I am so sorry for my bad question actually my english is very bad. but your answer worked for me.